# How to iterate through two generic lists with different types one item after another in java?

Tags: java, list, generics, iterator, wildcard

I want to create an iterator class which allows me to iterate through lists with generic types (e.g. lst1 integer, lst2 string) one item after another.
For this I have to consider the following given situation.

The interface is a generic Iterator. This part of the code cannot be modified.

```
interface Iterator<E> {
E next ();
boolean hasNext();
}
```

The list class is also defined as following. The most important, a list object can return a iterator object with the method getIterator(). This part of the code cannot be modified.

```
class List<T> {
class ListNode {
    T val;
    ListNode next;

    ListNode (T v) {
        val = v; next = null;
    }
}

ListNode head;

List (ListNode hd) { head = hd; }
List () { this(null); }

void prepend (T val) {
    ListNode p = new ListNode(val);
    p.next = head;
    head = p;
}

//some other methods

class ListIterator implements Iterator<T> {
    ListNode pos;

    ListIterator () {
        pos = head;
    }

    public T next () {       
        T res = pos.val;
        pos = pos.next;
        return res;
    }

    public boolean hasNext () {
        return pos != null;
    }
}

Iterator<T> getIterator () {        
    return this.new ListIterator();
}
}
```

Lets assume both list have the same type and for now they have also the same length. I tried to create a class with two iterator objects and used the methods of the iterator objects to implement the interface Iterator. This part of the code is created by me and can be modified.

```
class ZipIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>
{
int counter;
Iterator<T> first;
Iterator<T> second;

ZipIterator (Iterator<T> f, Iterator<T> s)
{
    first = f;
    second = s;
    counter = 0;
}

public T next ()
{
    if (counter % 2 == 0)
    {
        counter++;
        return first.next();
    }

    else
    {
        counter++;
        return second.next();
    }

}
public boolean hasNext ()
{
    if (counter % 2 == 0)
        return first.hasNext();
    else
        return second.hasNext();
}
}
```

This works fine for two list with the same type. Here is the code and the output I used for the test:

```
class IteratorUtils
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    List<Integer> lst1 = new List<>();
    List<Integer> lst2 = new List<>();
    lst1.prepend(3);
    lst1.prepend(2);
    lst1.prepend(1);
    lst2.prepend(8);
    lst2.prepend(9);
    lst2.prepend(10);
    Iterator<Integer> it1 = lst1.getIterator();
    Iterator<Integer> it2 = lst2.getIterator();
    ZipIterator<Integer> zit = new ZipIterator<>(it1, it2);
    while (zit.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(zit.next());
    }
}
}
```

Output:

```
1
10
2
9
3
8
```

Now I want to implement the ZipIterator in a generic way, so I can use two lists with different types of items (e.g. integer and string). I know I have to change the class ZipIterator so the method next() returns a generic type but I don't know how.
This is a university task i have to do and the prof has left a hint "use wild cards like: ? extends T, ? super T, ? extends Object". But with the wild cards i can only specify the types in or against the inherits direction, right? Is this possible to change the ZipIterator class that way so it accepts two iterator objects with different types?

Comment: Are there any constraints on the two types?  If not, the best you can do is return `Object`.

Comment: Which part of the code you posted is a given in the assignment and which part can you modify?

Comment: Well, I could give the answer, but that would take away all the difficulty of the assignment. I can give a hint though, take a look at [PECS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

Comment: The classes Iterator and List are given and cannot be modified. All the other code is made by me and can be modified. I will try to return Object and check out PECS.

Comment: To be clear (I'm currently writing an answer and this came up), do you have to have the `implements Iterator<...>` in your class, or you did it yourself?

Comment: @ user1803551 the class ZipIterator is completely made by me. It is my attempt to solve the task. I first tried to implement it in an easy way for two list with the same type. So there is surely another way but this was mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't give the full solution (and judging by your effort you don't want it), but I will attempt to explain in a way that will let you find it yourself.

First of all an unrelated note: you're specifying a specific iteration order. I assume this is fine and I will not touch it.

Your professor gave you the hint of using bounded generics. Let's understand why they are needed (see also the [tutorial here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) and/or [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)). If you were asked to write a single method that takes an argument of any of 2 unknown types, your solution would be to find and take their common superclass - `Object`.

In generics the situation is similar - find the most common denominator, only the syntax is a bit more tricky. If you were to write the constructor

```
ZipIterator(Iterator<Object> f, Iterator<Object> s) {...}
```

and attempt the initialization

```
List<Integer> lst1 = new List<>();
List<String> lst2 = new List<>();
new ZipIterator(it1, it2);
```

you would get a compilation error (read it). That is because a `List<String>` is not a `List<Object>`, even though a `String` is an `Object`. The correct way to do this is

```
ZipIterator(Iterator<? extends Object> f, Iterator<? extends Object> s) {...}
```

where `? extends Object` means "any type that extends `Object`" (which is all of them because `Object`...).

So you have the constructor, and you would need to make changes to your class in order to accommodate it. You don't even need to implement the given `Iterator<E>`, you just hold 2 of those like you already do. Lastly, the class itself need not have a generic type: since its `next` method must be able to return any type, it always returns `Object`.

If you have any questions during your future attempts at this problem, or you find that this solution doesn't fit the assignment's requirements, feel free to post a comment.

Answer (score 0):

> I know I have to change the class ZipIterator so the method next() returns a generic type but I don't know how.

That's not quite right. Since `ZipIterator<T>` extends `Iterator<T>`, it's actually set in stone that its `next()` method must return `T`. And this makes sense: the whole point of the iterator's type parameter is to let you specify the type that its `next()` method will return.

Instead, all your professor wants is for it to be possible to *construct* a `ZipIterator<...>` from two iterators with different type arguments. For example, (s)he wants to be able to write:

```
List<Integer> listOfIntegers = ...;
List<String> listOfStrings = ...;

ZipIterator<Object> zipIterator =
    new ZipIterator<>(listOfIntegers.getIterator(), listOfStrings.getIterator());
```

Note that, since `zipIterator.next()` will sometimes return an `Integer` and sometimes a `String`, we had to go with something like `ZipIterator<Object>` that allows for both possibilities. Other options included `ZipIterator<Serializable>` or `ZipIterator<Comparable<?>>`, since `Integer`-s and `String`-s are both `Serializable` and both `Comparable<?>`.

---

So the problem that your professor wants you to solve is that in your current code, your *constructor* requires both iterators to have the exact same type argument (as each other, and as the `ZipIterator` itself):

```
ZipIterator (Iterator<T> f, Iterator<T> s)
```

Do you see how to fix that?

Comment: Read the comments to the question. Your initial assumption is not so accurate.

Comment: @user1803551: I did read the comments, and I stand by my "assumption". The `implements Iterator<T>` is essential to the design, and we shouldn't throw it away just because the professor left it to the student to write it. Maybe the student can find an "easy way out" by dropping that bit and taking partial credit on the assignment, but why would you encourage that?

Comment: If it's design then it's not "set in stone" - it's a choice. I don't see why you assume that not implementing it will result in partial credit. We have no information on the grading method nor any specific requirements. I also don't see why dropping it is an "easy way out", if it's not necessary then dropping it is the right choice. If anything, the professor hints at using wildcards in the solution.

Comment: @user1803551: The return-type of `next()` is set in stone because `ZipIterator<T>` (correctly) implements `Iterator<T>`. Re: "I don't see why you assume that not implementing it will result in partial credit": The purpose of the assignment is, obviously, to learn about generics and wildcards. So if the OP were to pointedly avoid generics when they're obviously the right approach, simply because (s)he couldn't get them working, I *hope* the professor would take a few points off. Re: "the professor hints at using wildcards in the solution": Yes, absolutely. My answer relies on that. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

as i understand you want to iterate over list of different types one of solution is to make your constructor accepted iterator fulfill the requirement that it being iterator of any thing that extends object but this will limits your use of the retrieved items to just use it as objects or you will have to cast them to achieve further tasks a less restrictive approach is to make the constructor accepted iterator fulfill the requirement that it being iterator of any thing that extends the nearest common ancestor like this `ZipIterator(Iterator<? extends T> f, Iterator<? extends T> s)` so your class will look like this

```
class ZipIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    int counter;
    Iterator<? extends T> first;
    Iterator<? extends T> second;

    ZipIterator(Iterator<? extends T> f, Iterator<? extends T> s) {
        first = f;
        second = s;
        counter = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        if (counter % 2 == 0) {
            counter++;
            return first.next();
        } else {
            counter++;
            return second.next();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (counter % 2 == 0) {
            return first.hasNext();
        } else {
            return second.hasNext();
        }
    }

}
```

then to use it you can specify the best appropriate super class that both types converge to it, in cases of it is `Object` you can write `ZipIterator<Object> zit =` ,the following code will show you an arbitrary use case

```
        List<StringBuilder> bl= Arrays.asList(new StringBuilder("hi i'm builder"));
        List<String> sl = Arrays.asList("hi i'm string");
        ZipIterator<CharSequence> zit = new ZipIterator<>(bl.iterator(), sl.iterator());
        while (zit.hasNext()) {
            CharSequence cs = zit.next();
            System.out.println(cs.subSequence(6,cs.length()));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I have learned a lot. Here comes my solution and some more explanations to the task.

Please notice first, that the design of the ZipIterator class is not set in stone. ZipIterator was designed by me. There may be another solution but this was my attempt.

To specify the task: "Please construct a class IteratorUtils with several methods. The method zip receives two iterator objects and returns one iterator object, which iterates alternating through the items of the two received iterator objects. The iterator returned by the zip function should stop after the last item of the shorter iterator object. Use wildcards so you can apply the zip function to diffrent types of iterator objects."

For this I first created the class IteratorUtils. Please notice that the design of the zip function is also not set in stone. In the task it only says: "The method zip receives two iterator objects and returns one iterator object, which iterates alternating through the items of the two received iterator objects."

```
class IteratorUtils
{
static ZipIterator zip (Iterator<? extends Object> first, Iterator<? extends Object> second)
{
    return new ZipIterator(first, second);
}
}
```

Then I created the class ZipIterator. After reading through your answers and some tutorials I understood the meaning of bounded type parameters in this task. Like user1803551 said, the ZipIterator class should not be generic. I just had to realize that I hat to find the common superclass (here Object). So I had to change my ZipIterator class to the following:

```
class ZipIterator
{
int counter;
Iterator first;
Iterator second;

ZipIterator (Iterator<? extends Object> f, Iterator<? extends Object> s)
{
    first = f;
    second = s;
    counter = 0;
}

public Object next ()
{
    if (counter % 2 == 0)
    {
        counter++;
        return first.next();
    }

    else
    {
        counter++;
        return second.next();
    }

}

public boolean hasNext ()
{
    if (counter % 2 == 0)
        return first.hasNext();
    else
        return second.hasNext();
}
}
```

In my main method I use the following code:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    List<Integer> lst1 = new List<>();
    List<String> lst2 = new List<>();
    lst1.prepend(3);
    lst1.prepend(2);
    lst1.prepend(1);
    lst2.prepend("three");
    lst2.prepend("two");
    lst2.prepend("one");
    Iterator<Integer> it1 = lst1.getIterator();
    Iterator<String> it2 = lst2.getIterator();
    ZipIterator zit = zip(it1, it2);
    while (zit.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(zit.next());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
one
2
two
3
three
```

Comment: Good! One thing about your solution: don't leave the `Iterator` fields as raw types - make them generic as well. One thing about your question: you added the explicit rules in your answer here, but it would have helped if you were to add them in the question to avoid confusion. Best practice is to quote the assignment exactly.